sqlite: behavior of WITH...AS clause
I am having trouble understanding how WITH...AS clause works. In my understanding, it is used to name sub-query and I can refer to that sub-query using its name in the main query. But somehow the below code raises "no such column" error:

expected result: names of all employees who have higher salary than anyone in Marketing department (i.e. Alice,Sarah)

WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT MAX(EmployeeSalary)
    FROM Employee
    WHERE DepartmentName = 'Marketing'
    GROUP BY DepartmentName
)
SELECT EmployeeName
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeSalary > T1;

Table schema:
CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeNumber SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
EmployeeName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
EmployeeSalary INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
DepartmentName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES Department,
BossNumber SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeNumber));

Sample data:
1   Alice   75000   Management  \N
2   Ned 45000   Marketing   1
3   Andrew  25000   Marketing   2
4   Clare   22000   Marketing   2
5   Todd    38000   Accounting  1
6   Nancy   22000   Accounting  5
7   Brier   43000   Purchasing  1
8   Sarah   56000   Purchasing  7
9   Sophie  35000   Personnel   1
10  Sanjay  15000   Navigation  3
11  Rita    15000   Books   4
12  Gigi    16000   Clothes 4
13  Maggie  16000   Clothes 4
14  Paul    11000   Equipment   3
15  James   15000   Equipment   3
16  Pat 15000   Furniture   3
17  Mark    15000   Recreation  3

Could someone show me why the WITH...AS clause does not work in this case? Thanks a lot!

Somehow the query runs just fine if I replace the ">" operator with "IN" keyword (but does not return the correct result of course), or if I just use the sub-query directly like below:
SELECT EmployeeName

FROM Employee

WHERE EmployeeSalary > (

    SELECT MAX(EmployeeSalary)

    FROM Employee

    WHERE DepartmentName = 'Marketing'

    GROUP BY DepartmentName

);


When you have fixed the column name, you will still have a subquery returned more than one row error.

Sample table data is great, but a complete [mcve] also includes the expected result. (It's not obvious what you are trying to do.)

Oh sorry, I just made an edit to main post. expected result: names of all employees who have higher salary than anyone in Marketing department (i.e. Alice,Sarah)

Can you please specify the expected result.

A WITH clause, aka CTE (common table expression) is like CREATE VIEW. The difference is that a created view gets stored in the database and you can access it in any query, while the CTE is an ad-hoc view valid only in the query it belongs to.
CREATE VIEW t1 AS 
(
  SELECT MAX(employeesalary) AS max_salary
  FROM employee
  WHERE departmentname = 'Marketing'
);

creates a view named T1 in your database. From then on you can use this view as if it were a table that gets filled when running the query. The same applies to the WITH clause. Note that you must give the resulting column a name (max_salary here), because columns in a table need a name.
You can use it like this:
SELECT * FROM t1;

or like this:
SELECT max_salary FROM t1;

You cannot, however, use it as if it were a column:
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE employeesalary > t1;

What would that even mean? You want employees with a salary greater then the T1 table? Instead you would have to select a column from the table:
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE employeesalary > (SELECT max_salary FROM t1);

This works because the subquery returns a single value: one row, one column. For this reason you can place it in your query where one would expect a value. If a subquery can return more rows, then you need another operator, e.g.:
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE employeesalary > ALL (SELECT max_salary FROM t1);

As far as I know, SQLite doesn't support the ALL operator, though, so you would have to find other means, e.g. a NOT EXISTS clause in case you are dealing with a view containing more than one row.
At last here is the example with a view retuning no more then one row
WITH 
  marketing AS
  (
    SELECT MAX(employeesalary) AS max_salary
    FROM employee
    WHERE departmentname = 'Marketing'
  )
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE employeesalary > (SELECT max_salary FROM marketing);

and one example with a view returning more rows:
WITH
  marketing AS 
  (
    SELECT employeesalary
    FROM employee
    WHERE departmentname = 'Marketing'
  )
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM marketing
  WHERE marketing.employeesalary >= employee.employeesalary
);


You need to alias the max employee value, and then select from your CTE in a subquery:
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT MAX(EmployeeSalary) AS maxsal
    FROM Employee
    WHERE DepartmentName = 'Marketing'
    GROUP BY DepartmentName
)

SELECT EmployeeName
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeSalary > (SELECT maxsal FROM T1);


This is a way to do it using INNER JOIN :
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT MAX(EmployeeSalary) AS maxsal
    FROM Employee
    WHERE DepartmentName = 'Marketing'
)
SELECT EmployeeName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN T1 ON e.EmployeeSalary > maxsal

GROUP BY is unnecessary because we are already filtering by DepartmentName.
Demo here
